# How long does a D&D battle usually last? How can length be reduced?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, dungeons-and-dragons

I was a bit astonished when I noticed that battle in my last game ran for 1h30. That was for a party of 4 6th-level characters, played by 2 players. It was a mechanical battle, with minimal, if any, role play.

Is this an usual length? What "range" of battle lengths is usual in D&D?

Of course, number of rounds might be very important, so maybe it is more useful to talk about the length of a single round. What is the usual range of for the time it takes to complete a round? Would a 2 minute round be practical? Would a 10 minute round?

I might want to reduce the time try to increase the pace of combat, but I need to know what speeds can, in your experience, be achieved reasonably.

Comment: I think this is likely to get closed as opinion-based, based on the lede question: "how long should a battle last?" Your last question--"tips to reduce the time"--is probably well-posed and you can almost certainly find good answers to that already on the site. (I'll look for some to link.)

Comment: @nitsua60 Yep, we have [a lot](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=speed+up+combat) of questions on this subject.

Comment: I dropped the "how long should it last".
I just want to know about other peoples experiences, and some times for reducing length

Comment: is the length a *problem*? *I.e.* are you three having fun playing long battles? Or are two enjoying and one bored?

Comment: I am a little bored (btw, I am a player, not the GM). The GM and the other player seem fine with it. But mostly I wanted to know if our 1h30 hour battle was exceptionally lengthy or something relatively ordinary, and what are the experiences of other players regarding battle time

Comment: "How long should a battle last" isnt very answerable. "How can we shorten battles" or "how can I keep myself interested in long battles" are very valid questions.

Comment: Ok. I dropped that part of the question.
But I still really want to know if, in the experience of the players around here, a 1h30 hour battle has a "surprisingly long" duration

Comment: @josinalvo The thing is, that's a survey question. I might say yes, someone else might say no, and there's no way to judge which is the better answer. Questions on this site have to have objectively best answers, so survey-type questions just don't really work here.

Comment: That seems pretty typical for that level.  It varies with the power of the combatants, as well as the number.  Simple 1st level combats might take 20 minutes or less.  Conversely, I've had battles with dozens of combatants on each side, of high level (12th or more) run for 14 hours of play time (to cover about 90 seconds of character time).